# How can I increase memory in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am fetching data from a streaming API, in JSON. After around 8000 articles, I run into this error. The error page in Laravel 4 points me to some file in Guzzle, but I am still confused.
How does one increase memory in Laravel 4.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7246207 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a PHP ini setting and relies on the setting you have set in with your PHP installation.

You can set ini settings on the fly with `ini_set` on a per request basis.

I would suggest making your application a little more memory efficient if you are running into these problems though. Scrap (`unset`) variables you have finished using etc.

Comment: I am taking care of memory, but maybe something is wrong in my recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The below line will set the memory limit to unlimited

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
```

Comment: This would be a very bad practice and should be used only in a very exceptional and controlled environment.